# Mention the CPU Family type in config to build Linux Kernel for a particular CPU architecture?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, cpu, intel

I am trying to build `Linux Kernel 5.18.5` downloaded from `kernel.org` for a `Intel Xeon IceLake` CPU. My build machine is an `Ubuntu` machine on `Intel i7 processor` . Is there a CONFIG change needed in the `.config` to mention the CPU type I am building for?

Comment: would be pertinent you give the version / release of the kernel you downloaded.

Comment: @MC68020, Stable release 5.18.5 my kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

The only important kernel config setting is found under **Processor type and features / Processor family** sub menu. it will only impact on basic kernel compilation settings. (gcc's -march for instance)

In terms of CONFIG_* options this should translate into some CONFIG_[LABEL] option where [LABEL] represents the family chosen amongst for instance MK8, MPSC, **MCORE2** (the one I suggest you should be using for your Xeon), MATOM, GENERIC_CPU)

The original list might appear somehow limited but everything else ([some patches suggesting a much wider list exist](https://github.com/graysky2/kernel_compiler_patch)) would only impact very specific and dedicated compiler optimization settings that are better not to be set for compiling the kernel since it would become definitely unsupported.